# set_position and set_size_inches does not work properly when overlaying imshow and scatter in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

I am trying to create an image from a matrix `z2` over a raster defined by `np.meshgrid(grid_x, grid_y)` such that the value of the image at `vx=grid_x[i], vy=grid_y[j]` is `z2[i, j]`. On top of this image, I am trying to add a scatter plot of a number of points obtained by three vectors `x, y, z` such that the i-th point has the coordinate `(x[k], y[k])` and the value `z[k]`. All of these scattered points lies within the region of the aforementioned raster.

Here's an example of the aforementioned data I am trying to plot.

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1)
z2 = np.ones((1000, 1000)) * 0.66
z2[0, 0] = 0
z2[-1, -1] = 1
x = np.random.rand(1000) * 1000
y = np.random.rand(1000) * 1000
z = np.random.rand(1000)
grid_x = np.linspace(0, 999, 1000)
grid_y = np.linspace(0, 999, 1000)
```

In order to do this, I am using a 2D plot where the x and y values are used to define the position of the points and z is indicated by a color drawn from a colormap.

What is required of this image is that 1) there should be no white space between the actual plot and the edge of the figure; 2) the unit length on the x and y axis should be equal; 3) the image should not be too large. In order to achieve these, I am using the following code for plotting.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm

def plot_img(x, y, z, grid_x, grid_y, z2, set_fig_size=True):

    # determine the figure size
    if set_fig_size:
        height, width = np.array(z2.shape, dtype=float)
        dpi = max(max(640 // height, 640 // width), 1)
        width, height = width * dpi, height * dpi
        plt.gcf().set_size_inches(width, height)
        plt.gcf().set_dpi(dpi)

    # plot the figure
    plt.gca().axis('off')
    plt.gca().axis('equal')
    plt.gca().set_position([0, 0, 1, 1])
    plt.xlim((grid_x[0], grid_x[-1]))
    plt.ylim((grid_y[0], grid_y[-1]))

    # the raster
    cmap = cm.get_cmap('gray')
    cmap.set_bad(color='red', alpha=0.5)
    plt.imshow(z2, cmap=cmap, interpolation='none', origin='lower',
                   extent=(grid_x[0], grid_x[-1], grid_y[0], grid_y[-1]))

    # the scatter plot
    min_z, max_z = np.min(z), np.max(z)
    c = (z - min_z) / (max_z - min_z)
    plt.scatter(x, y, marker='o', c=c, cmap='Greens')

    plt.show()
```

Strangely, when I run `plot_img(x, y, z, grid_x, grid_y, z2)` using the aforementioned example data, the following image shows up.

[image]

Essentially, only the raster data got plotted, while the scattered data is not.

I then tried `plot_img(x, y, z, grid_x, grid_y, z2, set_fig_size=False)`. The result is

[image]

Note that here to clearly show the white spaces in the figure, I kept the background of PyCharm surrounding it. Essentially, there are white spaces that I do not wish included in this figure.

I wonder why this is happening, and how I can fix the code to get the correct output, which is essentially the second result without the white spaces. Thanks!

Comment: Your equation for dpi is incorrect and makes the dpi less than one.  You want something like npixels / inches and you have npixels / npixels (or really you always have a dpi of 1)

Comment: @Jody Klymak I explicitly set dpi to be at least one by using dpi = max(max(640 // height, 640 // width), 1)

Comment: Yes but you don’t want a dpi that is so low. 1 dpi means that you figure is six pixels wide and 5 high.  Instead of plotting a grey image plot a random matrix (np.random.randn(1000,1000)) and you should see that you only have a few pixels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your dpi and figsize code by

```py
# determine the figure size
height, width = np.array(z2.shape, dtype=float)
dpi = 200
# get size in inches:
width, height = height / dpi, width / dpi
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(width, height)
plt.gcf().set_dpi(dpi)
```

and you will have a 1000x1000 pixel figure, which at 200 dpi is 5"x5".

Comment: This works! Thanks a lot! Although I think width, height = height / dpi, width / dpi should be width, height = width / dpi, height / dpi

Comment: I do have one more question. What exactly is the relationship between resolution (in pixels) and dpi, width (height). Suppose I have a large raster (say 10000 * 10000) to plot. Obviously I don't want a 10000 * 10000 image. I assume in this case I should divide width (height) by an additional factor other than dpi (that is I want to set width, height = width / dpi / factor, height / dpi / factor). How to I set this factor? Thanks!

Comment: Usually you decide what size to make your figure, and allow matplotlib down or upsample your image to whatever resolution.  You should be careful about downsampling, though, as it can cause aliasing.